# Scheduling array of 3 elements avoiding deadlock

Tags: java, arrays, queue, iteration, scheduling

Given an array of 3 ["0","1","2"] string elements in total, all initially rendered as available, the maximum number of elements that can be assigned is 2, after 2 elements have been assigned (Scheduled), no more elements can be assigned. Based on this premise, the following scenario can occur.

(note: Easy to understand from code)

Scenario 1: process P1 requests an element, and is assigned element "0"(element "0" then becomes unavailable to be assigned to any other process, since its held by process P1), then process P2 requests an element and is assigned element "1" - and now the array has reached its max scheduling capacity. Any process (P1/P2) can abandon it's element at any given time. If process P2 abandons its element "1", then process P3 requests an element, it should be given/assigned element "2" (since element 2 has never been assigned). Any process (P1/P3) can abandon it's element at any given time. If process P1 abandons its element "0", the next available element that can be assigned is element "1" (since two elements ("1","0") in the array are available. This whole cycle can occur for P(n) processes, provided that the rule of no more than two is maintained.

How can I assign a MAXIMUM of 2 elements, at all times, avoiding starvation of elements? (given that processes,in any order, can abandon their elements)

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    myScheduler p = new myScheduler();

    /* available elements: "0","1","2" imagine them being in a queue */
    /* elements taken: non */
    String show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "0"

    /* available elements: "1","2" imagine them being in a queue */
    /* elements taken: "0" */
    System.out.println(show);

    show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "1"

    /* available elements: "2" queue cannot be empty */
    /* elements taken: "0","1" imagine them being a linked list (at most 2 elements can be taken) */
    System.out.println(show);

    show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "full"
    /* available elements: "2" queue cannot be empty */
    /* elements taken: "0","1" note: it didn't change (at most 2 elements can be taken) */
    System.out.println(show); 
    show = p.abandonElement("1"); //Should return "1"
    /* available elements: "2","1" imagine them being in a queue */
    /* elements taken: "0" */
    System.out.println(show);
    show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "2"
    /* available elements: "1" queue cannot be empty */
    /* elements taken: "0","2" (at most 2 elements can be taken) */
    System.out.println(show);
    show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "full"
    /* available elements: "1" queue cannot be empty */
    /* elements taken: "0","2" note: it did not change (at most 2 elements can be taken) */
    System.out.println(show);
    show = p.abandonElement("0"); //Should return "0"

    /* available elements: "1","0" */
    /* elements taken: "2" */
    System.out.println(show);
    show = p.requestElement(); //Should return "1"

    /* available elements: "0" */
    /* elements taken: "2","1" */
    System.out.println(show);
}
public class myScheduler {

private String [] array;
public myScheduler()
{
    array = {"0","1","2"};
}
public String requestElement(){
    /*This function returns the element given to this request, if array has already assigned 2 elements, return "full" */
}

public String abandonElement(String element){
    /*This function returns the element to be abandoned, if the element doesnt exist, return "not found" */
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Right now your question is very broad. (Essentially how can I write this program in java) Could you narrow it down to a single, specific question please?

Comment: @GBlodgett , I tried narrowing it down. Is that more clear?

Comment: Yes that is much more clear. Thank you! (I'm guessing this is a homework problem) Did your instructor give any requirements of using an array? Can you use a `hashmap`?

Comment: @GBlodgett Yes it is a homework assignment, Unfortunately we are unable to use a hashmap.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a queue?

Comment: @GBlodgett yes we can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I would do: Construct a `LinkedList<>()` to keep track of which times were booked first. (Queue's are FIFO- First In First Out) Then create a `final ArrayList<>()` to keep track of the times you can book. (You only want your users to be able to book `0, 1,` and `2`)

Here is my code:

```
//Add the three choices. Make the ArrayList final so nobody can change it
public static final ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(); {{
    array.add("0");    
    array.add("1");
    array.add("2");
}}
public static LinkedList<String> linked = new LinkedList<>(); {{
  linked.add("0");
  linked.add("1");
  linked.add("2");
 }}

public String requestElement(){
    /*This function returns the element given to this request, if array has already assigned 2 elements, return "full" */
   String result = "full";  //Assume the result is full
   if(linked.size()==1) {  //If only one time is available return full 
       return result;
   }
   result = linked.poll();    //Poll the first item on the queue
   return result;
}
public String abandonElement(String element){
    /*This function returns the element to be abandoned, if the element doesnt exist, return "not found" */
    String result = "Not Found";
    if(array.contains(element)) {   //If the arrayList contains the element, add it back to the LinkedList
        linked.add(element);
        result = element;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot @GBlodgett. This, not only works, but makes so much sense now.